# Select item from Dropdown in Internet Explorer page with VBScript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to open a URL and select value from the dropdown and then submit the form but I am not able to select the value from the dropdown.

[image: HTML of URL]

This is my current code:

```
Dim vb
Dim ie

Set vb = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'start IE
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm"

'Loop until page load
Do While ie.Busy
    WScript.Sleep 200
Loop
WScript.Sleep 200

'Activate ie windows
vb.AppActivate ("NSE - National Stock Exchange of India Ltd. - Internet Explorer")
WScript.Sleep 200

'Now i want to select from dropdown, How can i select option from dropdown list.

'Submit the form
ie.Document.All.Item("dataform").Submit

Set vb = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you loop through all options and select the one you want:

```
For Each objOption In ie.Document.getElementById("bankNiftySelect").Options

    With objOption
        If .Value = "foSec" Then
            .Selected = True
        Else
            .Selected = False
        End If
    End With

Next
```

Comment: Thank you sir, when we change the selection from dropdown site page update accordingly but when we select from the drop-down using this process site page not update.

Comment: Sir, Actually I found-    
ie.Document.getElementById("bankNiftySelect").selectedIndex = 38
ie.Document.getElementById("bankNiftySelect").FireEvent ("onchange")

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use the following code:

```
        For Each objOption In IE.Document.getElementById("bankNiftySelect").getElementsByTagName("option")
            With objOption
                If .Value = "foSec" Then
                    .Selected = True
                Else
                    .Selected = False
                End If
            End With
        Next
```

Comment: Thank you sir, when we change the selection from dropdown site page update accordingly but when we select from the drop-down using this process site page not update.